# Is it possible to reuse a T4 class feature in the generated code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, t4

I'm creating a C# file using a T4 template. I would like to reuse of the class features in my template, `GetListOfItemsToLoopOver()` in the generated C# code.
Is it possible to do this without creating a new assembly?

Comment: Can you provide more details? The main way to use T4 to add features to classes is by way of `partial class` syntax. Would that work or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn it around: put your `GetListOfItemsToLoopOver()` method in a standalone C# source file in a class, and add that source file to your project. You can then also include that source file in your T4 template (using the [T4 Include directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586949.aspx)).

You will need trivial differences between the T4 version and the non-T4 version, at least relating to the `using`, `namespace`, and perhaps also the `class` bits, but that's easily handled by using `#if T4`...`#endif` blocks, and making sure the `T4` symbol is defined when running the template.

It's easy to accidentally change your source file in ways that only work for one of the places it gets used, though, so do add a comment that the T4 template should be re-tested when changes are made.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll keep the functions apart since the main thing I want isn't worth maintaining #if blocks.